# Prove that diophantine equation has only two solutions.

Tags: number-theory

I am looking at the following exercise:

$$\text{Prove that the diophantine equation } x^4-2y^2=1 \text{ has only two solutions.}$$

That's what I thought:

We could set $x^2=k$,then we would have $k^2-2y^2=1 \Rightarrow 2y^2=k^2-1 \Rightarrow 2 \mid k^2-1$

Can I use this fact or do I have to do it in an other way?

**EDIT**: Or could we do it maybe like that:

$k^2-2y^2=1 \Rightarrow (k-\sqrt{2}y)(k+\sqrt{2}y)=1 \Rightarrow k-\sqrt{2}y= \pm1 \text{ and } k+\sqrt{2}y=\pm 1 \Rightarrow  k-\sqrt{2}y=1 \text{ and } k+\sqrt{2}y=1 \text{ OR } k-\sqrt{2}y=-1 \text{ and } k+\sqrt{2}y=-1$

The second case is rejected,because then we get $k<0$

$$k-\sqrt{2}y=1 \text{ and } k+\sqrt{2}y=1 \Rightarrow k=1 \text{ and } y=0 \text{ OR } k=0 \text{ and } y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \notin \mathbb{Z}$$

So, $k=1 \Rightarrow x^2=1 \Rightarrow x=\pm 1 \text{ and } y=0$

So,the only two solutions are $(1,0) \text{ and } (-1,0)$

Comment: How does that fact help you? I don't see how it even gets close to finishing the problem.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese I edited my post..could you tell me if it is right now??

Comment: You're assuming that $k \pm \sqrt{2}y$ are integers, but they aren't.

Comment: And of course $k^2-2y^2=1$ has infinitely many solutions in integers.

Answer (score 4):

You are doing it right. $x^4 - 2 y^2 = 1 \Leftrightarrow x^4 -1 = 2 y^2 \Leftrightarrow (x-1 ) ( x+ 1 ) ( x^2 +1 ) = 2 y^2$.

Now prove that $x$ is odd, then $x = 2 k +1 $, and show that $k ( k+1) ( 2 k^2 + 2 k + 1)$ is a square, and since each factor is relatively prime, $k$ and $k+1$ are squares, conclude that $k=0$ and $x=1$ and $y=0$.

Comment: Why is each factor relatively prime?

Comment: And also,why if two numbers are relatively prime,they are squares?

Comment: Use euclidean algorithm:

$\gcd ( k, k+1) = \gcd ( k, 1) = 1$
$\gcd ( k , 2^k + 2 k + 1 )  = \gcd ( k , 1 ) = 1$
$ \gcd ( k+1, 2k^2 + 2k + 1 ) = \gcd ( k + 1, 2k ( k + 1 ) + 1 )  = 1$

Comment: If $a \perp b$, and $a b = x^2 $, then $a$ and $b$ are perfect squares: take a prime $p$ divisor of $a$, and suppose that $p^{\alpha} || a$, since $a\perp b$, $p^{\alpha} || a b = x^2 $ so $\alpha$ is even. The conclusion is that $a$ is a square number.

Comment: @PenasRaul there is a typo in your coment. The second gcd should say $gcd(k, 2k^2+2k+1)$, instead of $gcd(k, 2^k+2k+1)$

Answer (score 2):

$$2y^2=x^4-1=(x^2+1)(x^2-1)=(x^2+1)(x+1)(x-1)$$

Suppose that $2y^2$ has an odd prime factor $p$. Then $p^2$ divides $y^2$, and hence, $p^2$ divides $(x^2+1)(x^2-1)$. Since $p$ can not divide both factors, then $p^2$ divides $x^2+1$ or $p^2$ divides $x^2-1=(x+1)(x-1)$. Thas is, $p^2$ divides $x^2+1$, $x+1$ or $x-1$.

This proves that each factor $x^2+1$, $x+1$ and $x-1$ is a perfect square or the double of a perfect square. And there are $1$ or three of them that belong to the second group. The factor $x^2+1$ is a perfect square only if $x=0$, which gives no solution for $y$.
If there is only one double of a perfect square, then we have that $x+1=u^2$, $x-1=v^2$. But then $u^2-v^2=(u+v)(u-v)=2$, and this is impossible since $u+v$ and $u-v$ have the same parity.
If there are three doubles of squares, then $x+1=2u^2$, $x-1=2v^2$ and $2(u^2-v^2)=2$, that is, $u=\pm1$, $v=0$. This gives $x=\pm1$ and $y=0$, and there are no more solutions.

Comment: So,it is: $(x-1)(x+1)(x^2+1)=2y^2$ , and it can't be that $x$ is even,so it must be of the form: $x=2k+1$.
$$$$
Replacing this,we get: $$4k(k+1)(2k^2+2k+1)=y^2$$

So, $k,k+1,2k^2+2k+1$ must be a square.So:
$$k=a^2$$
$$k+1=a^2+1=b^2$$
$$b^2-a^2=1 \Rightarrow a=0, b=\pm 1 \Rightarrow k=0$$
$$\text{Therefore, } x=1$$

If I do it like that, I get only one solution.So,is this way wrong?