# Prove this equation has only two integer solutions

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

The problem:

> Prove that the only integer solutions of the equation $x^3=y^2+2 $ are $x=3$ and $y=\pm 5 $.

I found these related posts:
[Prove that diophantine equation has only two solutions.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/839586/prove-that-diophantine-equation-has-only-two-solutions)
[Show that $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = x^3 + y^3 + z^3$ has infinitely many integer solutions.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1732049/show-that-x2-y2-z2-x3-y3-z3-has-infinitely-many-integer-soluti)
[Show that $x^2-dy^2 = -2$ with $d = m^2+2$ has infinitetly many integer solutions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2645723/show-that-x2-dy2-2-with-d-m22-has-infinitetly-many-integer-solution)

I have tried techinques similar to the ones used in those posts, however I have not been able to solve it yet.

**Edit:** The first comment gave me the hint of working in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$.

$$x^3=y^2-(-2)=(y+\sqrt{-2})(y-\sqrt{-2}) $$
And we define $a:=y+\sqrt{-2}$ and $b:=y-\sqrt{-2} $. Now I need to prove that $a$ is a cube in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$. As a side note, that would imply that $b$ is also a cube in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$. Once I prove that, I can use the answers in the post titled "[The only natural number $x$ for which $x+\sqrt{-2}$ is a cube in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$ is $x=5$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1719328/the-only-natural-number-x-for-which-x-sqrt-2-is-a-cube-in-mathbbz-sq)", and solve the problem.

How can I prove that $a$ is a cube in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$ ?

Comment: factor in the Euclidean domain $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$, etc.

Comment: @user10354138 thanks for your comment! I edited my question to show what I did thanks to your hint.

Comment: perhaps try solving for $c$ and $d$:
$$ \left (c + d \sqrt -2 \right)^3 = y + \sqrt -2$$

Comment: @jonan You are assuming that what we want to prove is true. You cannot do that in mathematics. We can only use the fact that the product $ab$ is a cube, because that is all we know.

Comment: @evaristegd if we want to prove that 25 is a square, we are looking for an integer solution to the equation: $x^2 = 25$. If such a solution exists, we say 25 is a square. If no such solution exists, we say it is not a square. Am I correct in stating this? If I am, then I do not see how my prior comment is invalid as you are suggesting, with all due respect.